# How would I copy a file before packaging a jar in maven as last step of install?

Tags: maven, maven-antrun-plugin

I am trying to overwrite a file with a new one before packaging the final jar in my final step of maven install.  Trying this with "antrun" plugin but somehow not working. Goal unpack is working.  Is it because I have no goal? What goal/phase would I specify here? Is the order of plugins incorrect? Any ideas?

```
<artifactId>my-deploy</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>apps.my-deploy</name>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>rsdk-download</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>my-apps</groupId>
                                <artifactId>r-sdk</artifactId>
                                <version>3.0</version>
                                <type>zip</type>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/lib</outputDirectory>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-myfile</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <copy file="../deploy/jsw/lib/my-new.jar" tofile="../deploy/jsw/lib/my.jar"/>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>../deploy/jsw</directory>
            <!-- Filtering adds about a minute to build time -->
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**</include>
                <include>**/*</include>
            </includes>
       </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `verify`, the jar is already built, so you need to manipulate content before the `package` phase.